# How do I get my Heroku site to start working again after they performed maintenance on it?

Tags: heroku

I have (had) a site on Heroku for months (free account) and it worked great. A day or two ago, I received an e-mail that read:

"Your database DATABASE_URL on {redacted} requires maintenance. During this period, your database credentials will become read-only. Once it has completed, your database URL will have changed, but we will update your app's config variables accordingly. This automated maintenance is a necessary part of our Hobby tier plans, Dev and Basic. Should you need more control over maintenance windows, a production database (Standard tier or higher) offers more control over database maintenance, as we are able to schedule them in advance and provide better tools for self-served maintenance. We expect maintenance to last just a few moments depending on the size of the database. We will notify you when maintenance begins, and again once it's complete."

Although I received an e-mail a few minutes later saying that maintenance completed successfully, I can no longer use the site, as whenever I visit the URL, I see the following:

"Application error - an error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command heroku logs --tail."

Please help! I tried to contact Heroku for help but I was directed here.

Comment: Can you please paste application log here?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Here is what the application log says: 2019-10-20T23:18:13.201855+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host={redacted}.herokuapp.com request_id=34ceb6cc-cf87-4f97-8368-6019a458b7ea fwd="174.95.43.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2019-10-20T23:18:13.465468+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host={redacted}.herokuapp.com request_id=0c3e57c9-29d9-44ef-aa34-ff017a7a3f66 fwd="174.95.43.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: Can you confirm the Procfile and dyno.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry, I'm new! It's a free dyno, if that helps. What information do you need, specifically?

Comment: Please add new database, copy data from old to new and then promote new database as primary. Sometimes there are some issues while connecting with database after maintenance

Comment: That sounds really difficult and I might not have time to try it until Christmas holidays but I will check back then and let you know how it went. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have tried all of this but it's still giving the same error message. Oh well!